# Chilkat - Generating single Json array from two arrays

Tags: json, activexobject, chilkat

Lets say you have the following Chilkat JsonObject named jsonA:

```
"object": "list",
"data": [
 {0},
 {1},
 {2},
 {3},
 {4},
 {5}
],
"has_more": true
}
```

Lets say you have the identical following JsonObject named jsonB:

```
"object": "list",
"data": [
  {6},
  {7},
  {8}
  ],
  "has_more": false
  }
```

Utilizing the bundle, what would be the best approach to generate a single "data" array of:

```
"data": [
{0},
{1},
{2},
{3},
{4},
{5},
{6},
{7},
{8}
],
```

I've dug through the Json reference documentation and cannot seem to find a method that would do this? Each array can contain up to 100 items, so I would rather not have to loop through each item if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do..

First.. the syntax "{0}" doesn't make sense to me.  If the array item begins with "{", then it should contain a name/value pair such as:  "name" : value

```
            string strA = @"
{
""object"": ""list"",
""data"": [ 0,1,2,3,4,5 ],
""has_more"": true
}";
            string strB = @"
{
""object"": ""list"",
""data"": [ 6,7,8 ],
""has_more"": false
}";

        Chilkat.JsonObject jsonA = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
        jsonA.Load(strA);

        Chilkat.JsonObject jsonB = new Chilkat.JsonObject();
        jsonB.Load(strB);

        Chilkat.JsonArray a = jsonA.ArrayOf("data");

        int numDataItems = jsonB.SizeOfArray("data");
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<numDataItems; i++)
            {
            jsonB.I = i;
            a.AddIntAt(-1,jsonB.IntOf("data[i]"));
            }

        jsonA.EmitCompact = false;
        textBox1.Text = jsonA.Emit();
```